# SerializationException: could not serialize. Calling a Stored Procedure with an Oracle Array parameter and returning a cursor

Tags: java, oracle, serialization, procedure

Im getting this exception when executing the procedure query procedureQuery.execute() and im not sure why is this happening.

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not serialize 

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.serialize(SerializationHelper.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

This is the method ive been trying to run:

```
public List<MyEntity> fetchMyEntityAttrs(List<String> idList) {
    StoredProcedureQuery procedureQuery = entityManager
        .createStoredProcedureQuery("my_entity_pkg.get_attrs", MyEntity.class)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("array", ARRAY.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("cursor", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

    String[] idArray = idList.toArray(new String[0]);
    Object[] values = Arrays.stream(idArray).toArray();
    try {
        Connection connection = datasourceConfiguration.dataSource().getConnection();
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
        Array oracleArray = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("VARCHAR2_ARRAY", values);
        procedureQuery.setParameter("array", oracleArray);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    procedureQuery.execute();

    return procedureQuery.getResultList();
}
```

I've been reading that it could be due to the Connection class not being serializable but the way of converting a java array to an oracle array and passing it to the stored procedure is the same everywhere I look.

Answer (score 0):

to set an ORACLE array as procedure parameter you should use .setArray() not .setParameter()

Comment: StoredProcedureQuery does not have .setArray()

Comment: right: it's on PreparedStatement, so we may suspect that Hibernate doesn't do the right thing at time to give the parameter to the JDBC layer, we should look in the source code to be sure.

Comment: Latest version of Hibernate has a setParameter accepting a BindableType as 3rd parameter, you should check if the version you are using has this one too.

Comment: Then setParameter("array", oracleArray, OracleArrayJdbcType.INSTANCE) should work.